# JQuery class structure: Syntax error on calling function

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

I'm new to JQuery and trying to implement a function which will hide an input element on click. I keep getting a syntax error.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="grad">
        <div id="blah">
            convo
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="topimage"><img src="assets/scrybe.jpg" width="100px"></div>
</div>

<form>
    <input id="filter" onkeyup="blah.test()" placeholder="Search" type=
    "text">
</form>

<div id="leftcontainer">
    <input id="userlist" placeholder="Find people" type="text">
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
var usersearch = {

   $('#filter').click();

   //ready: function(){
   $("#filter").click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
   });
   //}
};

//usersearch.ready();
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the input on DOM Ready? Why?

Comment: What syntax error do you get?

Comment: I want hide the input element 'filter' on userclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working, check this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tHbGh/

Change your JQuery to this:

```
var usersearch = function() { 

$('#filter').click();

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filter').click(function () {
        $("#filter").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It keeps giving me the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' error now.

Comment: That's because you are calling the ready function before the JQuery Javascript is included

Answer (score 0):

The JS code as you have it written is invalid and produces a "syntax error". It has nothing to do with jQuery, just a standard JS syntax error. In this case, `var usersearch = {` begins a JSON object, but the code that comes immediately afterwards does not follow JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
function usersearch(){

   $('#filter').click();

   //ready: function(){
   $("#filter").click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
   });
   //}
};

//usersearch.ready();
```

Is this what you meant to do? Make sure you define functions correctly.

Comment: I want usersearch to be a class and click to be a method in that class.